# PKI-based x.509 certificate authentication with SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, x509certificate, pki

In a 2-tier client/server legacy application (SQL Server 2008 R2) where AD is **not** used I would like to add user authentication and authorization based on x.509 PKI certificates without having to use IPSec or similar.

The client could use an existing STS/WS-trust service to obtain a signed SAML-token prior to contacting the SQL Server.

The SSL option of SQL Server does, from what I have found so far, not support mutual (2-way) authentication. One thought was to have a custom .NET stored-procedure performing the authentication (or SAML-token validation) after which the users current SQL Server login is 'enabled' but surely there must be better options.

What would be a good approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) to create a certificate authenticated SSL endpoint and then use Windows Authentication or built-in SQL Server Authentication over the SSL protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen several projects trying to retrofit certificates into legacy client/server. One way to do it is to have a service on the server responsible for the SSL authentication (communication between this service and the SQL Server is not encrypted).

Depending on how much time you have, this solution has two extremes.

In the simplest case the SSL service only checks that the client certificate is valid and issued by the trusted CA. In a more complicated situation, the SSL service also maps the client certificate to an account and initiates the SQL login on the SQL Server (optionally with periodically changing passwords).

Comment: Thanks for really good input! And nice to hear others have done this already. The authentication service would be pretty straight forward but how do you see the database server 'prevent' login to the database if not authentication to the service is made prior to the connection. Stored-procudere?

Comment: I'd use a firewall or separate IP address.